# Does the custom variable sent by PayPal during subscr_signup match the one sent during subscr_cancel?

Tags: paypal, subscriptions

On the [Subscriptions and Recurring Payments Variables](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside) page, it's shown that the custom variable is sent for the `txn_type` of `subscr_cancel`. Since there's no way to send a new custom variable, does that mean PayPal is sending the same custom variable sent during `subscr_signup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

I discovered that I could check the IPN message sent by PayPal by visiting **Profile > Preferences > Instant Payment Notification preferences > IPN History page** and then clicking the appropriate **Message ID** link.